# automatic script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, sudo, init

I have an Ethereum node running and mining on a terminal in Linux. I want to create a script that will start up the node.sh roughly 2 minutes after startup. My script is in the home/chainskills/private/startnode.sh. I want this to be executed after startup. I have barely any knowledge of Linux. Please help me. I was told to go and create a script in the etc/init.d directory but I don't know how to. I am running this on a Ubuntu 18 on a mini-mac. I have followed the instructions on many pages on how to automate this script. I need to use the init.d and not a cronjob. Please help.

Comment: why not a cronjob ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a cronjob:

Run `crontab -e` and add following line:

```
@reboot sleep 120 && /home/chainskills/private/startnode.sh > /home/chainskills/private/startnode.log 2>&1
```

If you need to run your script as `root` user, run `sudo crontab -e` and add the line there.

Comment: hi the crontab does not work. i was instrusted that i had to do something in the folder "alex@alex-Macmini:/etc/init.d$"

Comment: maybe you need to run that script as root  ? see my edit. Also @Melebius, not sure, edited.

Comment: how do i run it as root

Comment: See my answer, it's in there. How did you run your script up to now ?

Comment: i use terminal and go to the file directory and i typed ./startnode.sh. i want this to run 2 minutes after startup of the device.

Comment: Okay, so you don't use root user. Please try again the changed crontab line, there was an issue with the redirection to the logfile.

Comment: how do i check that the process has started after boot?

Comment: See running processes with ps or maybe top. You will find information on how to do it ... the comments are not for extended discussion

Comment: not to be rude, your method wasn't working very well with my device and the remote startup is not working. Please provide me an alternative support path?